# Elastic Search query to check for null values in 2 fields

Tags: elasticsearch, notnull

What is the elastic search query to search for documents where "field1 is null **OR** field2 is null"..

I am using elasticSearch 5.3...

Answer (score 7):

This query did work for me:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/my_null_val/_search?pretty" -d '
{
  "query": {
    "bool":{
      "must_not":{
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {"exists" : { "field" : "field1" }},
            {"exists" : { "field" : "field2" }}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

As a hint you can think of `field1 is null **OR** field2 is null` to be equivalent expression to `NOT (field1 is not null **AND** field2 is not null)`.

It is also known as [De_Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Answer (score 1):

You could also get away with using a `should` clause in your `bool` filter.

```
    "bool": {
      "should": [{
        "bool": {
          "must_not": {
            "exists": {
              "field": "field1"
            }
          }
        }
      }, {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": {
            "exists": {
              "field": "field2"
            }
          }
        }
      }]
    }
```