# How can I write an "or" query in Elasticsearch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

I have this SQL:

```sql
select *
from users
where company_id = null
  or company_id = 123
```

How can I write a similar query in Elasticsearch?  I want the query to return all candidates who have a `company_id` that is `nil` or who have a `company_id` that matches the current user.

I have tried this with `should`:

```
query: {
  bool: {
    should: [
      {
        bool: {
          must_not: {
            exists: {
              field: "company_id"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        term: {
          company_id: 123
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This returns users whose `company_id` is `nil`.

I've tried this with regex also but it returns users who have a `company_id`.

```
query: {
  bool: {
    should: [
      {
        regexp: {
          comapny_id: ".+"
        }
      },
      {
        term: {
          company_id: {
            value: 123
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Which case fails for your first attempt?

Comment: 2nd one, that query only returns the user whose company_is is nil

Comment: Does this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43132240/elastic-search-query-to-check-for-null-values-in-2-fields) help? I am not that familiar with elastic search syntax

Comment: Your first attempt should work.  What is the data type of your `company_id` field?  When you just use the `term` query are you able to find a candidate with an ID of `123`?

Comment: company_id data type in elasticsearch was TEXT, because on active record it's datatype i UUID. no when i used only term that doesn't retuen candidate, i think my problem wih this term query.

Comment: @engineersmnky my 1st attempt used same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments you mentioned that the `company_id` is really a UUID and the type is currently `text`.  You should try to change your `company_id` to a `keyword` field.  You will need to reindex after making this change.

Elasticsearch doesn't recommend using a `term` query against a `text` field:

> Avoid using the `term` query for `text` fields.
>
> By default, Elasticsearch changes the values of `text` fields as part of analysis. This can make finding exact matches for `text` field values difficult.
>
> To search `text` field values, use the `match` query instead.
>
> [Term Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html)

Their suggestion here is to use `match`, but I don't think that you'll need to support partial matching against randomly generated UUID values, so I think you should define your field as a `keyword` instead.

Comment: worked thank you so much only when i change company_id type from text to keyword.

Comment: Can i run must with first one query, i want to satisfy both condition with and operator

Comment: Yes, if you're saying you want to check that a `company_id` exists you'd need to change the `must_not` to `must`.  If you're saying you want to require both filters to be `true` you'd need to change the `should` to `must`.